# Trying to underline the first occurence of a character with Javascript/Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have some anchor tags where I'm using an angular directive to decorate (underline) the text(to indicate a keyboard shortcut). So far my code only works if the specified character (for "amt-alt-key")   is at the beginning of the first word. 
  What I need to do is search the whole string and underline the first occurrence of the specified character. So right now if I specified an amt-alt-key="A" in the example below it would work fine as is. However, the problem is the first occurrence could be anywhere in the anchor text. Any help with writing the correct JavaScript would be greatly appreciated.

--Jason

```
 In my html
 <a href="#/Agent" amt-alt-key="P">Agent Data</a>

 In my angular code
 app.directive("amtAltKey", function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            var altKey = attrs.amtAltKey.toUpperCase();
            var text = el.innerText;
            var textUpper = text.toUpperCase();
            var indexOfKey = textUpper.indexOf(altKey);

            var newText = text.substring(0, indexOfKey);
            newText += '<u>' + text.substring(indexOfKey, 1) + '</u>';
            if (indexOfKey + 1 < text.length) { newText += text.substring(indexOfKey + 1); }
            el.innerHTML = newText;
            keyListeners[altKey] = el;
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regular expression to check the required pattern and a `replaceText` utility function to replace the matched pattern and once you have the text, replace the existing content of the element as below:

```
.directive('amtAltKey', function () {
   return {
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      var altKey = new RegExp(attrs.amtAltKey, 'i');
      var text = elem.text();

      function replaceText (txt) {
        function underline(match) {
          return '<u>' + match +'</u>';
        }
        return txt.replace(altKey, underline);
      }

      var newText = replaceText(text);
      elem.html(newText);
    }
  };
});
```

Here is a working example: https://jsbin.com/zefodo/2/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
app.directive("amtAltKey", function () {
return {
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        var altKey = attrs.amtAltKey;
        var text = elem.innerText;

        elem.innerHTML = text.replace(new RegExp(altKey, 'i'), '<u>$&</u>');

        keyListeners[altKey] = elem;
    }
};
});
```

Comment: I corrected the answer to make it case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
app.directive("amtAltKey", function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      var el = elem[0];
      var altKey = "" + attrs.amtAltKey.toUpperCase();
      var text = el.innerText;
      var textUpper = text.toUpperCase();
      var indexOfKey = textUpper.indexOf(altKey);
      if (indexOfKey > -1) {
        var newText = text.substr(0, indexOfKey);
        newText += '<u>' + text.substr(indexOfKey, 1) + '</u>';
        if (indexOfKey + 1 < text.length) {
          newText += text.substr(indexOfKey + 1);
        }
        el.innerHTML = newText;
        keyListeners[altKey] = el;
      }
    }
  };
});
```